# Angular 5: Map a json to a class instance

Tags: angular, rest, model, httpclient

I have a class model defined as User in the following way:

```
export class User {
    private code: string;

    get Code(): string {
        return this.code;
    }

    public setCode($code: string) {
        this.code = $code;
    }
```

In the main component I have a part like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  private $user: User;


  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  public loadUser(): void {
    this._http.post<User>(Global.url + '/user/show',
        {}).subscribe(
        data => {
          if (null !== data) {
            this.$user = data;
            console.log(this.$user);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            this.$user = null;
          }
        }
      );
  }

  public get User(): User {
    return this.$user;
  }
}
```

The page to open makes a query of the user, the server returns the code in json format and should map it with the User Class. This is what it returns:

```
{…}
​
code: "B1039"
​
...
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

But if I try to access the values through the properties "console.log(this.$user.Code)", this is what returns me:

```
undefined
```

That is to say, although in my IDE it takes that the variable data is of the type User Class, the methods to access do not work.
Why is not the json returned not converted to the User object?
I need to use a model class but not an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the constructor yourself. Casting `<Something>data` doesn't call it for you, it only describes for the TS compiler which interface the data should look like. So for instance you could do:

```
this.user = Object.assign(new User(), data);
```

Or a common way is to make that same assignation in the class constructor, so you can just `new User(data)`.

Comment: I did it in the following way: constructor(data) {
    this.code = data.code;
  } Thanks

Comment: Does Object.assign get compiled in ES5?

Comment: I don't think so, use polyfills anyway if you want to support old IE.

Comment: Or defaults() or defaultsDeep() from lodash :)

Answer (score 0):

I preferred a safer way to do it

```
export class AppComponent {
  private _user: User;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getUser(): Observable<User>{
      return new Observable(observable => {

            if(!!this._user){
                observable.next(this._user);
                observable.complete();
            }
            else{
                 this._http.get<UserResponse>('...some....')
                    .map(this._mapUserResponse)
                    .subscribe((mapped:User) => {
                         this._user = mapped;

                         observable.next(this._user);
                         observable.complete();
                 }, err => {
                      observable.error();
                 });
            }

      });
  }

  private _mapUserResponse(response:UserResponse):User{
       if(!!response && !!response.foo){
            return new User(response.foo, response.bar);
       }
       return void 0;
  }

}
```